# How to show an inequality of integral

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, young-inequality

I’m reading a paper in which there is an inequality as
$$ 2k\phi (L,t)\int_{0}^{L}{{{e}^{-\frac{\mu x}{2}}}\phi (x,t)dx}\le \left( \frac{r{{e}^{-\mu L}}}{2} \right){{\phi }^{2}}(L,t)+\left( \frac{2L{{k}^{2}}{{e}^{\mu L}}}{r} \right)\int_{0}^{L}{{{e}^{-\mu x}}{{\phi }^{2}}(x,t)dx}$$
where $k,r,μ,L$ are three independent positive constants and $ϕ$ is a continuous function of $x,t.$

In the paper, the authors hinted that they used the Young and Cauchy–Schwarz inequalities to get this result, but they haven’t given any further details. Can anyone help me to show this inequality?

Comment: $k, r, \mu, L$ are three independent positive constants,  $\phi$ is a continuous function of $x,t$. There are no more relations between these quantities. Do you have some ideas to this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the notations, let

- $\psi(x,t):=e^{-\mu x/2}\phi(x,t)$
- $\alpha:=\frac r2$
- $\beta:=kLe^{\mu L/2}.$

Your inequality rewrites
$$\frac{2\beta}L\psi(L,t)\int_0^L\psi(x,t)dx\le\alpha\psi^2(L,t)+\frac{\beta^2}{L\alpha}\int_0^L\psi^2(x,t)dx$$
i.e.
$$ 2\alpha\beta\psi(L,t)\int_0^L\psi(x,t)dx\le L\alpha^2\psi^2(L,t)+\beta^2\int_0^L\psi^2(x,t)dx,$$
which is equivalent to the following obvious one:
$$\int_0^L\left(\beta\psi(x,t)-\alpha\psi(L,T)\right)^2dx\ge0.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your proof is excellent. I want to ask a pressing question. How to use the Young's inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality to derive from the left end of the inequality to the right end. Because in applications, we only know the expression at the left end, what we need to do is to find its right end.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. That (new) question is too vague for me.